# Preventing direct typing into a UITextField when using an inputView to show a UIPicker on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uipicker, inputview

I have code working very nicely to show a picker on a `UITextField` object (in a `UITableViewCell`) by using the `inputView` of the `UITextField` object.  This stops the keyboard being shown but does not stop someone directly typing into the field.

To be fair they can only paste something in but even so that should not be allowed if you do not want a custom value in the field.

Is there anyway of turning the text input off?  I've tried:

```
return NO;
```

in the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing()` delegate method but this only serves to prevent the field operating at all - so no picker comes up.

Are there any other ways of preventing this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `UITextFieldDelegate` method

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)string
```

This will be called any time that something tries to change text in your text field.  You can do a simple check that the `string` value is something you would expect it to be (something from your picker view), otherwise discard it.  If the `string` value is what you want, return `YES`, otherwise return `NO`

Comment: Thanks - that does work.  It does not stop the cut/copy/select commands being available or the cursor appearing in the field but it does stop anything being changed.  You don't need to do the string comparison as the text value can be changed in the textFieldDidEndEditing delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

How about using another UITextfield that's offscreen?  The uipicker is then the inputview for the offscreen textfield.  In the handler for when the date picker changes, the original textfield's text property is specified to be updated.  Tapping on the original textfield to bring up the picker is handled one of several ways:
1. The textfield is always set to userInteractionEnabled = NO, and there's an invisible button over it that detects touches.
2. The textfield in the cell is replaced by a label, and touching in instead detected by the cell with didSelectRowAtIndexPath.
3. The textfield in the cell, after it detects the touch, the delegate then sets the textfield in didBeginEditing to userInteractionEnabled = NO (not sure if this would work).

Come to think of it you could even try #3 without creating a second textfield.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do is disable sub menus.

To do this sub-class UITextField and implement the following method

```
(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return NO;
}
```

This will prevent the menu from showing.

Comment: Could you elaborate how a submenu being on/off prevents text from being typed/copied into a UITextField?